# Cannot install FFI library for Lua/LuaJIT

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit, luarocks

I have already correctly installed Lua, LuaJIT and Luarocks (I can run each of them in the terminal without any errors too). I'm trying to run the command `luarocks install luaffi` but it is returning an error

```
Error: No results matching query were found for Lua 5.4
To check if it is available for other Lua versions, use --check-lua-versions.
```

So I tried running `luarocks install luaffi --check-lua-versions` which also returns the following:

```
Checking if available for other Lua versions...
Checking for Lua 5.1...
Checking for Lua 5.2...
Checking for Lua 5.3...

Error: No results matching query were found for Lua 5.4.
luaffi is not available for any Lua versions.  "
```

I'm completely lost, I cannot use `ffi` in my code because of this (It returns module "ffi" not found).

Comment: FFI is only available in LuaJIT and LuaJIT use a Lua 5.1. Did you already read: https://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html ?

Comment: An FFI library does exist for vanilla Lua, but you should find it and build manually.  Maybe Luarocks does not have it.  Or use LuaJIT - it includes FFI by default.

Comment: OK - I see - Have tried and successfully built it: https://github.com/zhaozg/lua-ffi - It installs also Lua 5.1 when call: ```luarocks make```

Answer (score 1):

After the build (See: https://github.com/zhaozg/lua-ffi ) you can use Lua 5.1 to test it.

```
€ cat luajit_sleep.lua 
--[[
Lua JIT ffi Example - Implementing a Lua sleep() function from C
]]
  local ffi = require("ffi")
  ffi.cdef[[void Sleep(int ms); int poll(struct pollfd *fds, unsigned long nfds, int timeout);]]
  local sleep
  if ffi.os == "Windows" then
    function sleep(s) ffi.C.Sleep(s*1000) end
  else
    function sleep(s) ffi.C.poll(nil, 0, s*1000) end
  end

return sleep
€ /bin/lua
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> sleep = require('luajit_sleep')
> sleep(1) -- CPU friendly sleep() function :-)
```

It uses (`lsof | grep lua`)...

```
/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/ffi.so
```

EDIT - Found the Command to install: https://luarocks.org/modules/colesbury/luaffi
Do: `luarocks install --server=https://luarocks.org/dev luaffi --verbose`
Also goes to...

```
os.execute:     chmod '0755' '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/ffi.so'
Results: 1
  1 (number): 0
luaffi scm-1 is now installed in /usr/local (license: BSD)
```

Answer (score 1):

[cffi-lua](https://github.com/q66/cffi-lua) is what you are looking for. It is compatible with LuaJIT and Lua >= 5.1

```
$ luarocks install cffi-lua
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are mac os user (My case is M2)

try this: https://github.com/zhaozg/lua-ffi

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/luaffifb
cd luaffifb
luarocks make
```